# How come the exact same code works in one app but in a new app I'm getting "promise rejected". (React Native Push Notifications Demo)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, amazon-web-services, react-native

Below is the boiler plate to setup push notifications to iOS and Android using Amazon SNS as a middle man. It's just a demo. It worked fine in my first app but I tried copy pasting the code in a fresh React Native app and I cant even get the device token without getting a promise rejected error. How do I avoid that? I must admit promises are not one of my strengths. Below is the code for the entire app.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, Platform } from "react-native";
import * as Device from "expo-device";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: false,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
});

export default function App() {
  const [deviceToken, setDeviceToken] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Configure AWS SDK
    AWS.config.update({
      region: "process.env.AWS_REGION",
      accessKeyId: "process.env.AWS_ACCESS",
      secretAccessKey: "process.env.AWS_SECRET",
    });

    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(async (token) => {
      setDeviceToken(token);
      try {
        const SNS = new AWS.SNS({ correctClockSkew: true });
        const platformApplicationArn =
          Platform.OS === "android"
            ? "process.env.FIREBASE_ARN"
            : "process.env.IOS_ARN"; // ARN of your platform application in AWS SNS

        // Create platform endpoint and subscribe to topic
        const endpointParams = {
          PlatformApplicationArn: platformApplicationArn,
          Token: token,
        };
        const createEndpointResponse = await SNS.createPlatformEndpoint(
          endpointParams
        ).promise();
        const endpointArn = createEndpointResponse.EndpointArn;

        const subscribeParams = {
          TopicArn: "process.env.TOPIC_ARN", // ARN of the topic you want to subscribe to
          Protocol: "Application",
          Endpoint: endpointArn,
        };
        await SNS.subscribe(subscribeParams).promise();
        console.log("Successfully registered device with AWS SNS.");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        marginHorizontal: 25,
      }}
    >
      <Text>Your expo push token: {deviceToken} </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;

  if (Device.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } =
      await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
      alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
      return;
    }
    token = (await Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync()).data;
    console.log(token);
  } else {
    alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
  }

  return token;
}
```

Comment: Here is the error message: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method requestPermissionsAsync on module ExpoNotificationPermissionsModule: String resource ID #0xffffffff

Comment: Also getting this error:  line 93 [Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method requestPermissionsAsync on module ExpoNotificationPermissionsModule: String resource ID #0xffffffff]
 LOG  line 53 [MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Token' in params]